# WPF Images not rendering during runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a set of images that load from my solutions resource file, now they show up fine in design mode and in Blend but they won't show up at all when I actually run the program.

Here is the markup of the controls

```
<WrapPanel x:Name="heartsWrapPanel" Height="25.97" Canvas.Left="437.94" Canvas.Top="594.83" Width="75.26">
    <Image x:Name="heart1" Height="22.388" Width="24.777" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/heart.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="heart2" Height="22.388" Width="24.777" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/heart.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="heart3" Height="22.388" Width="24.777" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/heart.png"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

Now I can't figure out what's wrong, there's nothing wrong with the wrap panel as I've tried to put in other elements in it and they show up fine, and like I said the images show up in design mode and in Blend but it won't show up during runtime.

Comment: Do you see files copied to your output directory?

Comment: you have to set the "Build Action" to "Resource" for Images

Comment: If you start in the debugger (F5), do you see any messages in the output window within visual studio?

Comment: @Mate Turns out I had to do that and change to `Source=Resources/heart.png"`

Comment: @OverlyExcessive Great! I've added as a solution, you can accept it or close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set the **"Build Action"** to **"Resource"** for Images
and maybe change to **Source=Resources/XXX.png"**